# selection in the items of eclipse tree column

Tags: java, eclipse, tree, jface

For a tree with 2 columns like,

```
TreeColumn column1 = new TreeColumn(myTreeViewer.getTree(), SWT.LEFT);
column1.setText("Column 1");
column1.setWidth(400);
TreeColumn column2 = new TreeColumn(myTreeViewer.getTree(), SWT.LEFT);
column2.setText("Column 2");
column2.setWidth(100);
```

I can only select the items in the first column.

I can see that the selection is disabled in the 2nd column so,

Ho can I enable selection of items in the 2nd column ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add SWT.FULL_SELECTION to the styles when creating the Tree widget. This will allow you to click on a cell in either column to select a row. Note that you cannot select cells in SWT Table and Tree widgets. Only rows can be selected.

Comment: thanks Konstantin, Is there a way to add icon that acts as a button in the right side of any tree item ?
and it will have different functionality when selecting it than the tree item .
I'll appreciate if you could help

Comment: There are ways to do that, but you should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: great,
I posted a question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315477/add-icon-button-beside-tree-item-in-eclipse-tree